# Is there a test to check if a second derivative is always negative for a given interval?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Is there a test to check if a second derivative is always negative for a given interval?

I am currently evaluating the second derivative many times with incrementing intervals and checking if negative or positive.

However, this is computationally expensive for the given precision I need.

I am aware of methods to find the local minimum and maximum of functions, but is there a clean solution for my problem?

The function in question is a 5th degree polynomial.

Comment: would you like to share your function?

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh It is a 5th degree polynomial.

Comment: Couldn't you just numerically find the zeros of the second derivative (using something like Newton's method for example). Once you know the zeros, you simply have to make sure your interval doesn't contain a zero and that the second derivative is negative at any point inside your interval.

Comment: **draw a variation array**, starting with the sign of third derivative (it is quadratic so you can study it directly). Then the second derivative is $\searrow$ or $\nearrow$ on some intervals, find the minimum, maximum and determine if it annulates on the given interval.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the second derivative of your 5th degree polynomial (a 3rd degree polynomial itself) has any root in the given interval. There are a few methods for it: Newton, secant, etc. If it doesn't, and such 3rd degree polynomial has a negative value evaluated at any arbitrary point of the interval, you will know that it is negative on the whole interval (otherwise it would be contradicting Bolzano's theorem).